# How do I disable ChromeVox UI when printing?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, accessibility, screen-readers

The [ChromeVox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) for Google Chrome browser places an orange outline around content when selected on the screen.

This orange outline is also printed when printing a web page. See how button below is selected with orange outline and then also appears on print preview.

How do I disable this orange focus ring when printing?

[image: ChromeVox orange focus ring in print dialog]

Comment: Have you tried to de-select it before printing the content?

Comment: Thanks @jess. Once a user "clicks" somewhere, there is no option to de-select, only to select something else.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with print css media-queries!

The ChromeVox injects markup and styles into the `body` of the page that looks like this:

```html
<div aria-hidden="true" class="cvox_indicator_container  ...more classes...">
...more html markup...
</div>
```

So I updated my global CSS stylesheet to include the following:

```css
@media print {
  .cvox_indicator_container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Which worked great.

Then I got to thinking that I wanted to make sure this never changed even if ChromeVox changed their css to have greater specificity.

Then, I updated the css to:

```css
@media print {
  html body div.cvox_indicator_container {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

**Note:** This may be overkill, but certainly has more specificity.

Ideally the ChomeVox team would add something like this solution to their code. I tried to find their open-source repo… got close but failed. Halp?

Comment: Sarcastically speaking, disabling chromevox solves a lot of problems ;) I don't know is there is a team (someone somewhere?) still working on it. Bug tracker can be found here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=component%3AUI%3EAccessibility%3EChromeVox+